sum of square roots is bigger than square rootof sum
I am trying to solve this, but still have no idea how to tackle it.
$$\sum_{i=0}^n {\sqrt i} \geqslant \sqrt {\sum_{i=0}^n i}$$

do you know about convexity of functions? This would be a very helpful notion for this problem.

Yes I know about them, but could you give me a hint how could I use this knowledge to solve this problem?

$(\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{i})^2=\sum_{i=0}^n i + 2 \sum_{i\ne j}^n i\cdot j > \sum_{i=0}^n i $
$\implies  \sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{i}  >\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n i}$

Thank you very much.
